# java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver - COM.ibm.db2.jdbc.app.DB2Driver

Tags: java, jdbc, db2

I am trying to connect to database using DB2JDBC Type 2 driver. Below is my java code

```
try
{
    
    String urlPrefix = "jdbc:db2:";
     String url = urlPrefix + paramString1;
       String user = paramString2;
        String password = paramString3;
        
  log.debug(context, 1010, "Connecting to : " + paramString1);
  
  Class.forName("COM.ibm.db2.jdbc.app.DB2Driver").newInstance();
  localConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
  localConnection.setAutoCommit(false);
```

I have added db2java.zip to my calss path and db2jdbc.dll is available in C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\SQLLIB\BIN(Prior to this error I faced db2jdbc.dll not found error)

[image]

When I run my code am getting **java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver** exception. What am I missing. Should I check the versions of the driver I have downloaded.

Answer (score 2):

[DB2 JDBC Type 2 Driver is discontinued](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/10.1.0?topic=functionality-db2-jdbc-type-2-driver) since Db2 10.1.

> **Resolution**
>
> Use the IBM Data Server Driver for JDBC and SQLJ instead of the DB2
> JDBC Type 2 Driver. Refer to the task Upgrading database applications
> and subtask Upgrading Java applications that use DB2 JDBC Type 2
> driver.
>
> **If you use the DB2 JDBC Type 2 Driver to compile your Java
> applications or routines, you will receive an error as the driver
> cannot be found.**

Answer (score 0):

Java package names are class sensitive. The "COM" needs to be in lowercase:

```
Class.forName("com.ibm.db2.jdbc.app.DB2Driver").newInstance();
// Here--------^
```